# Cannot access DisposableBean and cannot access InitialzingBean

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to compile the oVirt open source project on fedora core 21,

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project builtin: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/jenkins/workspace/ovirt-engine_master_find-bugs_merged_nomvn/ovirt-engine/backend/manager/modules/builtin-extensions/src/main/java/org/ovirt/engine/extensions/aaa/builtin/kerberosldap/utils/ipa/SimpleAuthenticationCheck.java:[61,25] error: cannot access InitializingBean
[ERROR] /home/jenkins/workspace/ovirt-engine_master_find-bugs_merged_nomvn/ovirt-engine/backend/manager/modules/builtin-extensions/src/main/java/org/ovirt/engine/extensions/aaa/builtin/kerberosldap/LDAPTemplateWrapper.java:[145,31] error: cannot access DisposableBean
```

mvn -version shows :

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (NON-CANONICAL_2014-06-19T11:19:24_mockbuild; 2014-06-19T11:19:24+00:00)
```

On fedora core18 it works -

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (rNON-CANONICAL_2013-04-08_07-49_mockbuild; 2013-04-08 10:49:23+0300)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.9.11-200.fc18.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The spring that is being used is aligned to 3.1.1.RELEASE from what I can see
In both the machines.

Can you give a hand? I know I'm using code that implements InitialzingBean and DisposableBean, but still - if same spring version, how come it does not compile

Answer (score 0):

we had this problem and we had installed JDK 1.8. When we installed JDK 1.7 then this issue disappeared. Try it, maybe it is your case :)